# Host wireless hotspot with internal Wi-Fi chip

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, server, hotspot

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3 model B which runs Raspbian Jessie. I'd like to host an SSH or telnet server on it that my phone can connect to, even when the Pi is not connected to Wi-Fi or cellular.

I was going to use hostapd or similar to host a hotspot, then connect to that with my Android phone — problem is, the Pi's internal wireless chip doesn't seem to support master mode, which eliminates any chance of being able to use hostapd — there is absolutely no space for an extra wireless adapter in my project box, even the tiny coin-sized ones without an antenna.

Is it possible to host a Wi-Fi hotspot from my Pi 3's internal wireless card, or some kind of other solution that would allow me to host a constant telnet/SSH remote command shell for my Android to connect to — even when the Pi is on the road without a WiFi source?

P.S.: My phone does not have Wi-Fi hotspot functionality, so that's also out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 3B and the Pi Zero W both share the same Wifi and Bluetooth chip, **and they both support Wifi Access Point mode**. Here at my desk is sitting a cute little Pi Zero W that acts as a network bridge and indicator, bridging from wired Ethernet to Wireless. The wireless side is the Pi operating in Access Point mode. `hostapd` directly supports the 3B and 0W out of the box.

Make sure to install iw and hostapd. Remove the wpa supplicant reference from wlan0 in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and set a static IPv4 configuration for wlan0. Tell `dhcpcd` in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to keep its fingers off wlan0 using `denyinterfaces wlan0`. Configure AP mode, see also https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md. If you don't need routing/NAT and DNS then you can go with the isc-dhcp-server, instead of dnsmasq. Configure the IPv4 address range it has to serve, make sure it matches with your wlan0 static configuration.

Afterwards, you can `ssh` into your Pi by connecting to the Pis WLAN first, then use JuiceSSH or another SSH app to connect to the AP's static IPv4. I'm using this to maintain my network indicator Pi Zero W all the time.